# How do I test model based on Bookshelf/Knex without actually writing to DB?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, knex.js, bookshelf.js

If I define my model entities without specifying each table column like this:

```
let bookshelf = require('../config/database');

require('./role');

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    role: function() {
        return this.hasOne(Role);
    }
});

module.exports = bookshelf.model('user', User);
```

How do I create my Mocha/Sinon tests without writing to DB?

I've tried a simple and clearly failing test like this:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');

var user = require('../../models/user');

var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

describe('User model', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        sandbox.stub(user);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        // completely restore all fakes created through the sandbox
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('should return empty set before adding anything', () => {
        sinon.assert.callCount(user, 1);
    });

});
```

However, actually I got an error message:

```
  User model
    1) "before each" hook for "should return empty set before adding"


  0 passing (41ms)
  1 failing

  1) User model "before each" hook for "should return empty set before adding":
     TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
      at wrapMethod (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core/wrap-method.js:70:21)
      at stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:56:44)
      at Object.stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/collection.js:87:33)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/models/User.spec.js:10:17)
```

### UPDATE

```
var ModelsUser = require('../../models/user'),
    User = ModelsUser.User,
    Role = require('../../models/role'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    should = chai.should();


var assert = require('assert');

describe('User model', function () {

    var test_usr = {name: 'Test User', username: 'test_usr', role_id: 1};

    beforeEach((done) => {
        // making sure the test user is removed before any test
        User.query().del().then(() => done());
    });

    it('should return empty set before adding anything', (done) => {

        User.forge().count().then(function(total) {
            expect(total).to.equal(0);
            done();
        })
        .catch(err => done(err));
    });

    it('should return a valid user after insert', (done) => {

        User.forge(test_usr)
            .save().then((model) => {
                should.exist(model.id);
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => done(err));

    });

});
```

Comment: it is quite unclear what you are trying to stub? are you trying to stub a certain method on the user module, or trying to avoid to load some other dependency of the user module? really not getting it.

Comment: In my C# projects I'm able to create mocks for my entities and repositories, because I have the entities' properties already defined (almost like my DB tables and columns), however with Bookshelf I just define the models without the DB columns, thus I can't create a mock of my entities.

Comment: That was background info, but I was asking something more concrete :-) Your test code is not exercising any actual code - just asserting, which makes for a bad test. What do you want to prove with your test? 

You are also not creating the stub right. It needs two params, unless you are trying to do something else than stubbing an object with all its properties.

Comment: Actually my code "evolved" a bit since when I posted this question. My idea on using mocks was to decrease the time to run tests, but as I couldn't find how to do it, I switched Bookshelf to use SQLite with in memory database when in dev environment. I still don't have any business rules defined in methods of my models, so I'm writing simple tests to learn about it.

Comment: Maybe you can get something out of this thread on the Sinon list: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/831#issuecomment-198081263  The link is for some code that should be relevant for you. It is a module that is caching stuff either in memory or in Redis, and supports injecting fake versions of either. The thread also talks about alternatives to dependency injection, like link seams using `proxyquire`.